# Проблема перегнать байты в текст

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, hex

В общем когда пытаюсь перегнать байты в текст выдается такая ошибка

> ```
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 16: 
>     invalid start byte
> ```

Ошибка происходит на этой строке

> ```
> rt = codecs.utf_8_decode(bt)
> ```

Мне нужно чтобы он игнорировал эту строку или просто убрать b'' из значения в списке.

```
import codecs
text = open('main3.txt',"r")
line = text.readlines()

lis1=[]
lis2=[]
flag = 0 #1
g=0 #1
lis1.append("")


for x in enumerate(line):
    if x[1][:1] == "X":
       flag=1
    else:
        if flag==1:
            g+=1
            lis1.append("")
        flag = 0
    if flag==1:
        lis1[g]+=x[1][2:].replace("\n",'')

lis1.remove("")
for xml in lis1:
    bt = codecs.decode(xml, 'hex')
    lis2.append(bt)
    rt = codecs.utf_8_decode(bt)
    print(rt)
```

Текст из main3.txt

> ```
> 52464820020000004C02000022020000B80400002020202020
> 20202000000000B8040000140000003C56657273696F6E3E32
> 3C2F56657273696F6E3E1C0000003C466F726D61743E202020
> 20202020203C2F466F726D61743E202020180000003C456E63
> ```

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что исходно текст не в кодировке utf-8 (или это вообще не текст, а бинарные данные). Нужно понять что там за кодировка, и использовать нужный декодер.

Comment: @insolor, да думаю что сообщение битое кодировка utf-8. Сообщение просто битое.

Comment: Ошибка в какой строке? `text = open('main3.txt',"r")` или `bt = codecs.decode(xml, 'hex')`? Приводите, трассу стека ошибки, пожалуйста, а не просто текст. Кст, зачем вам `enumerate`, если вы все-равно работаете со вторым элементом -- значениям из `line`, т.е. можно просто использовать `for x in line:` и в цикле вместо `x[1]` обращаться сразу к `x`

Comment: @gil9red, подправил. И написла на какой строке ошибка

Comment: @Sheva12, сложно понять что не так. Добавьте еще пример текста из `main3.txt`, чтобы можно было повторить ошибку

Comment: @gil9red, добавил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы наверно хотели это сделать не так сложно:

```
import codecs

with open('main3.txt') as text:
    for line in text:
        print(codecs.decode(line.strip(), "hex")
              .decode("iso8859_5"))
```

---

Вывод:

> ```
> RFH L"И     
>    И<Version>2
> </Version><Format>   
>      </Format>   <Enc
> ```

Так как `"iso8859_5"` 1-байтовое кодирование, не будет никаких ошибок.

Вместо `"iso8859_5"` вы можете попробовать другой 1-байтовый кодек или `"utf_8"` (с почти тем же самым результатом), но в последнем случае добавите параметр `"ignore"` или `"replace"` для избежания ошибки — значит, последняя строка программы будет например

```
              .decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
```

Comment: А как вы поняли, что там `iso8859_5`? :)

Comment: @gil9red, это был только пример 1-байтового кодека; в дальнейшем тексте моего ответа я написал «вы можете попробовать другой 1-байтовый кодек или "utf_8"».

Answer (score 2):

Нужно знать какая кодировка использовалась, иначе будут проблемы вида `codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 16: invalid start byte`.

Вместо `codecs.utf_8_decode` использовал `bytes.decode` для того чтобы передать `errors='replace'`, иначе будет такая же ошибка, а так хотя бы разберется.

Пример:

```
import codecs

text = """\
52464820020000004C02000022020000B80400002020202020
20202000000000B8040000140000003C56657273696F6E3E32
3C2F56657273696F6E3E1C0000003C466F726D61743E202020
20202020203C2F466F726D61743E202020180000003C456E63
"""
text = text.strip()

new_text = []

for line in text.splitlines():
    data = codecs.decode(line, 'hex')
    text = data.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')
    new_text.append(text)

print(''.join(new_text))
# RFH    L  "  �              �     <Version>2</Version>   <Format>        </Format>      <Enc
```